# Button redirect to another page in Angular 5

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular5

Hello guys First of all i am learning angular 5 for the first time. What  i want is to redirect from page to another using a button.I don't know how to make it work.I am using angular 5. This is my code:

Home.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
 <button (click)="btnClick()">Add Employee</button>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
 <button (click)="btnClick()">Employee List</button>
</div>
<br>
```

**Home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    btnClick(){
        this.router.navigate(['/employees']);
    }
}
```

I don't have route.config but what i have is app.module.ts if i am doing anything wrong please tell me

app.module.ts:

```
...........
import { HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeesComponent } from './employees/employees.component';
  @NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  EmployeesComponent,
  EmployeeComponent,
  EmployeeListComponent,
  AppHeaderComponent,
  AppFooterComponent,
  HomeComponent,

],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  ToastrModule.forRoot(),



],
```

Comment: code looks good , what's the error you are getting with this ?

Comment: it doesn't work  when i click on the button

Comment: Can you update your question with details of your apps router config? It could be a problem with that. Also there may be an error as `'/employees'` does not exist on route, but `'employees'` does

Comment: i just edited and add app.module

Comment: I'm not seeing any RouterModule import in your app.module.ts file.

Comment: help me to solve or what should i do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to configure your application's routes first so the router outlet knows what component to load when ['/employees'] is called

there is a good explanation under : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

First, you must configure the route

```
import { HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeesComponent } from './employees/employees.component';
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
  { path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent }
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
  @NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  EmployeesComponent,
  EmployeeComponent,
  EmployeeListComponent,
  AppHeaderComponent,
  AppFooterComponent,
  HomeComponent,

],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  ToastrModule.forRoot()
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes),



],
```

then in your in your AppComponent HTML you need to use the router outlet (assuming you want your employees to show on the app component)

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: No toastrModule is for another method

Comment: what do you mean by configure your application's routes ?? i should create new route folder ?

Comment: I have included how to configure routes in my answer. Please also see the link to Routes documentation I supplied in my answer. My answer is just a rough guide that assumes you want to display your routes in the main app component